# Automate to arrange Data

Tags: vba

Got any Way to Arrange The data like the picture attached?

*the requirement is when the Column A Cell is empty then Column B Value will Move to previous not Empty Column A Row at Column B Cell.

[Example Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYe5r.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Long
 i = 1
  Do Until Cells(i, 2) = ""
    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
    On Error Resume Next
     Cells(i - 1, 2) = Cells(i - 1, 2) & "," & Cells(i, 2)
       Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete
          i = i - 1
        End If
         i = i + 1
        Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: do you have anyway to sorting this?for example like if Column A got same data then will combine together(not duplicate data).thanks